# In Casper, what is the incentive to store the entire chain?

Tags: evm

Do the validators need information from the blockchain to produce blocks, or is it enough just to store a few recent blocks? What is the incentive to use large amounts of storage to store the complete ledger (or when sharded, store the full shard)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not just in Casper, it's in every consensus protocol out there (to my knowlodge). Full non-miner nodes does not benefit economically from the veriffication process, but if you want to validate your transactions by yourself (you're a big user and you want to be more secure about your transactions), you can run a full node.

this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/82btph/is_there_any_point_running_nonmining_full_eth/) provides more explanation

Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

EIP 908: Reward clients for a sustainable network

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-908